# apache and tomcat logs response time difference

Tags: apache, tomcat, httpresponse

We have tomcat  for our java application with apache acting as reverse proxy

and we are plotting the response time in grafana.

Need to understand which log will be the right one for accurate response time?

Both apache and tomcat access logs have response time.

Comment: Are both servers on separate machines.??

Comment: Define "accurate": When tomcat is done and has delivered its content to the reverse proxy, it is free for other duty. When the reverse proxy is done piping the result to the client (potentially with caching, through a slow connection), it's free to do other stuff. The difference between the client starting to send and rendering to be completed is yet another option (but that won't be available server side). However, this is rather system administration, thus off-topic on stackoverflow IMHO - see [help/on-topic]

Comment: Both apache and tomcat are in same server.I was concerned about whether apache response time will include network latency as well.for eg:Time to first byte.Also whether tomcat response time shows only processing time of tomcat or will it include network latency as well.